# How to get image url from google nearby search api

Tags: json, google-maps, google-nearby

I am trying to find nearby places using google nearbyApi, its working as expected. But, the problem is i can't get the place image from the json response. Please have a look at the below code.

```
{
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 24.331058,
      "lng": 54.623759
    },
    "viewport": {
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 24.332406980291,
        "lng": 54.625107980292
      },
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 24.329709019708,
        "lng": 54.622410019708
      }
    }
  },
  "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
  "id": "6c79339941d125d001a2116834f3257346b150bd",
  "name": "Mafraq Hotel & Resort",
  "photos": [{
    "height": 4032,
    "html_attributions": [
      "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100504071164796744561/photos\">ناصر الكعبي</a>"
    ],
    "photo_reference": "CoQBdwAAAF_hJoCjWHzDXpfEWbS-Ubg3cPB1Eac2y7fy6HM0q1sb4TyOZdci4LUQi7Z8TYXVw-ZbjeSDXkg-wwHjr67Ib2Aluv5QChRl3C97gTmlseV7UpUnvyW3Vt4GmcyQGRhfEkhjimbqjkUE8qC-8dt7thsRXzw7TIaBrEii1wK5C7gUEhCfuLSsZdEZkgoMEy0luSyeGhTfNMKnTkqmzUlUtTwdO7Gwx8tDYQ",
    "width": 3024
  }],
  "place_id": "ChIJbURih5o3Xj4R4qP2Jcu8C8k",
  "rating": 3.9,
  "reference": "CmRSAAAAMdmAyoaneUbzSmqHVbG_SFpgdcRjKSxQcHmVLKO518kINmhukPJF5Qo8tju2Su7uekMOXRw5jJxiNbBzjHY7Cd72FjnYEbx87N2F3OZoAUfUC9XuJ52uJmiJtXKRk9SkEhAg9HLkwuO58r4iVvgBqnY8GhTVfRwqPvEULqLIqmYlyA3U6h_1pg",
  "scope": "GOOGLE",
  "types": [
    "gym",
    "lodging",
    "health",
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
  ],
  "vicinity": "Sheikh Maktoum Bin Rashid Road, Al Mafraq"
}
```

I am getting a photos array:

```
"photos": [{
  "height": 4032,
  "html_attributions": [
    "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100504071164796744561/photos\">ناصر الكعبي</a>"
  ],
  "photo_reference": "CoQBdwAAAF_hJoCjWHzDXpfEWbS-Ubg3cPB1Eac2y7fy6HM0q1sb4TyOZdci4LUQi7Z8TYXVw-ZbjeSDXkg-wwHjr67Ib2Aluv5QChRl3C97gTmlseV7UpUnvyW3Vt4GmcyQGRhfEkhjimbqjkUE8qC-8dt7thsRXzw7TIaBrEii1wK5C7gUEhCfuLSsZdEZkgoMEy0luSyeGhTfNMKnTkqmzUlUtTwdO7Gwx8tDYQ",
  "width": 3024
}],
```

But, I don't know how i can create an image from this array information. (I am working with web api and i need the image url)

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If I follow the instructions in the [Place Photos documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos), I get an image url that display the image.  How are you attempting to display the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `photo_reference` 
with

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=`

to get an image url:

```
let data = {} // the json response

let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=";

let photoRef = data["photos"][0]["photo_reference"];

let imageUrl = url + photoRef;
```

Comment: I had to put they key in the url. Other than that it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos)

**TL;DR**

A Place Photo request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?
```

- `maxwidth=`[width value in your json (photos[0] -> width)]
- `&`
- `photoreference=`[photos[0] -> photo_reference]
- `&`
- `key=`[your api key]

So your final URL will be

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=5184&photoreference=CmRaAAAADmroqcfJMAxlbbpIC4r8bk5jU-8fPx5udw2ng-XPvO9a-E46QlvggSxlgkxDsnjJyKacRSqvPkm69dbEvPlX6fgaGtEaApGROn-U6wDjpXlr5PTcjEDN6UACil904bHMEhAtOschikf4lATKyBULOsnLGhTQTXKMKJnV_Z_0kdqUIyh6ZIDZ0A&key=xyzyourapikey
```